# A way to limit the number of categories with `exp:channel:categories`?

Tags: templates, categories

Is it possible to limit the number of categories that are returned by the `{exp:channel:categories}` tag? If not is there an alternative (or dare I say add-on :P)

Obviously I could just use an SQL query for this, but if possible I would prefer to use one of the more standard built-in tags for this if possible.

**Use Case:**

- Categories have been manually ordered using the control panel.
- Only want the first 10 to be displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `{exp:channel:categories}` sadly does not have a `limit` parameter. [GW Code Categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/documentation) does have a `limit` parameter though (along with many other useful features when working with categories).

Comment: Lea, if Derek's answer is correct, please select it as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark to the left.

Comment: @CreateSean I actually did the first time, but this site kept showing error messages. Still, its definitely ticked now :)